# Yepnope & Modernizr screen.width Conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr, yepnope

I am trying to (locally) use Yepnope with Modernizr to load CSS & JS Files. So I can manage the files better, and code easily.

This is the currently layout:

```
Modernizr.load([
    {
        test: Modernizr.mq('all and (max-width: 1070px)'),
        yep: '/css/smartdevice.css','/js/smartdevice.js',
    }
    ,
    {
        test: Modernizr.mq('all and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1069px)'),
        yep: '/css/tablet.css','/js/tablet.js',
    },
    {
        test: Modernizr.mq('all and (max-width: 1070px)'),
        yep: '/css/screen.css','/js/screen.js',
    }
]);
```

The I am fairly new to JS but I have used jQuery on may occasions. However they all load at once, is there anyway I can load the CSS files based on the px width? (ref above values). I am aware that you could do this server side, however in my position.

It has to be local side in js... I currently code in SCSS. Everything is fine that end, it is just a case of injecting the files/showing file on window width.

I presume that I need to add an if statement, but any help would be greatly provided!

-Neil

P.S I am running locally, on a new iMac using CodeKit & SCSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yep: '/css/smartdevice.css','/js/smartdevice.js',` is illegal JS. If you want this to be an array, use `yep: ['/css/smartdevice.css','/js/smartdevice.js'],`. Anytime you see a comma inside a JavaScript object, pretend there's a newline, and you'll see what's going wrong here:

```
Modernizr.load([
{
    test: Modernizr.mq('all and (max-width: 1070px)'), // prop:val(=function)
    yep: '/css/smartdevice.css',                       // prop:val(=string)
    '/js/smartdevice.js',                              // ???
}
,...
```

Comment: Thanks, would you know how to remove objects based on there media query above.

I have still got issues with the code. It seems to load all the css files at once, not based on windows width...
I also removed content (jquery .remove(); via complete) but that does not get invoked?

Comment: the code you showed will load several .css files at 1070, I don't know what you're testing on, or your full code, so I can't tell you why it does what it does. That said, loading files based on the browser width  at load time is pretty bad, since people on desktop can resize their browser, and people on tablets/phones can change their screen orientation, changing the min/max width in effect. The whole point of media queries is to have several of them in one file, so that your site is responsive throughout, not just sized correctly once.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean.. I initially wanted to load JS on media widths. Because I had jQuery FadeIn's and SlideDowns.. However and at a mobile css being used I had no need to invoke the js at that time...

I suppose I got lazy and wanted to add the CSS at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Some suggestions:

1. Replace "all" with the label "only all"
2. Replace the "max-width: 1070px" in the first test with a mobile
   device width (320 etc)

Comment: You don't need to write almostly everything in big font size.