# Load different javascripts for different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I have 2 js codes, Code A and Code B , I want the code A to be used only when the max width of the screen is 800px.

And the Code B to be used when max width is 400, but Code A to be disabled.
Is there any way to switch between them according on the screen size if the device?

Code A:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {$("#touchcarousel-1").touchCarousel({"pagingNavControls":true,});});
```

Code B:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {$("#touchcarousel-1").touchCarousel({"pagingNavControls":false,});});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Comment: Easiest solution: `window.screen.width > 400 ? codeB() : codeA()`

Comment: See here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/06/using-window-matchmedia-to-do-media-queries-in-javascript/

Comment: Additionally, if your code is longer using jquery.getScript() conditionally  might be useful.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve? <strike>Sometimes</strike> Most times it's better to write code that works (although behaves differently) in all situations.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I have added the codes.they are the same except in one value " false/true"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(window).width();` to get the width and then just incorporate that into an `if` statement...

```
if ($(window).width() > 800) {
  // code for large viewports
} else if ($(window).width() < 400) {
  // code for small viewports
}
```

Combo this with `jQuery.getScript()` as others have suggested and it should be pretty painless...

Comment: Thank You Dryden for your help. I'll try it out. I have added the codes above.

Comment: I wasn't lucky :( could you please tell me how I combo it wih jQueyr.getScript. I really appreciate your help. I worked on it day and night but no hope. I added the js codes above if you can take a look please.

Answer (score 1):

If you're code resides in two different files, you could use Modernizr/Yepnope to load the scrips.

```
Modernizr.load([
{
    test: Modernizr.mq('all and (max-width: 800px)'),
    yep: '/js/CodeA.js',
    nope: '/js/CodeB.js'
}
```

[Yepnope & Modernizr screen.width Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279522/yepnope-modernizr-screen-width-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

using the condition of user p.s.w.g you can load scripts with query e.g.
http://devdocs.io/jquery/jquery.getscript

```
$.getScript("script.js", function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

loooong explanation can be found at [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file/950146#950146)